# Backbone model.save() requests pile up due to slow client connection

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm running an online psychology experiment using the [PsiTurk framework](https://psiturk.org/). The experiment consists of thousands of trials. In each trial, the user produces some behavioral responses, and **the JS frontend sends these responses (along with mouse movement data, reaction times and so on) to the backend using Backbone's model.save() method.
This works fine for clients with fast connections (effectively sending out a .save request once every few seconds), but for clients with a slow connection, the save requests pile up, causing a long queue of requests that takes dozens of seconds to clear.** Down the road, this leads to excessive delay when arriving to the final screen (which requires a successful final update).

What is the best approach to this problem? Monitoring and limiting the number of pending requests? aborting pending requests when arriving to the final screen (before the final model.save())? sending out async .save requests (how?)

Comment: The save requests should definitely be handled asynchronously. You would need to share your code to be able to help you further.

Comment: I would use a collection where many models could be saved periodically in one request. https://backbonejs.org/#Model-Collections

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to keep a counter to monitor unfinished requests (increment when sending out a request, decrement when finish/error events are called), so I can avoid sending out an update if there already a couple of open requests.